# CASE ELSE Minimum date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case, min

I have shipping data with multiple records per tracking number and dates and I want to create a temp table that identifies the correct first date. Most of the time the tracking number has a order description of "origin" that I want to use but there are times where this doesn't exist and so I want to only grab the first date that I have.

However, this code below is kicking out the min date for each `event_status_description` which isn't what I want. The goal is one `OrderTrack` and `event_date_time` record per tracking number. So if `event_status_description like '%origin%'` then return the date, otherwise grab the minimum date for that whole `OrderTrack`.

```
SELECT Distinct (RTRIM(trackingnumber) + LTRIM(CAST(intmontyorderid AS varchar))) AS OrderTrack,
    CASE 
        WHEN event_status_description like '%origin$' THEN event_date_time
        ELSE MIN(event_date_time)
    END AS OriginDate
INTO #OriginTable
FROM abookprod.dbo.tblUPStrackinghistory
GROUP BY trackingnumber, intmontyorderid, event_date_time, event_status_description
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be find the minimum of all `event_date_time` values when `event_status_description` is `like '%origin%'`, and `COALESCE` it with the minimum of all `event_date_time` values for each `OrderTrack`:

```
SELECT Distinct (RTRIM(trackingnumber) + LTRIM(CAST(intmontyorderid AS varchar))) AS OrderTrack,
    COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN event_status_description like '%origin%' THEN event_date_time END), MIN(event_date_time)) AS OriginDate
INTO #OriginTable
FROM abookprod.dbo.tblUPStrackinghistory
GROUP BY trackingnumber, intmontyorderid
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=93ac091e547b2e10fbda7f524ce5f1a1)